# Why z-index does not apply in this case

Tags: html, css

I have two elements, one for `header` and the other for `navbar`.
I want to apply `z-index`property to make the `header` on the top, then the `navbar` on the bottom.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header"><h2 id="logo">Logo</h2></div>
    <div id="navBar"><span>x</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#header {
    height:70px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index:20;
}
div#navBar {
    height:50px;
    padding-right:240px;
    line-height:45px;
    background:yellow;
    z-index:21;
}
div#header #logo {
    position:relative;
    right:-20px;
    bottom:-20px;
}
```

Also you can see the [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CE5b3/)

**Why this problem occur ?**
**And how to solve it ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For z-index to work you need to set position on those elements: absolute, relative, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the header text appearing above the nav bar?  Perhaps you could try moving the header div tag into the beginning of the nav bar div tag.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you just switch the z-indices. Lower index means bottom. You have the larger index on the bottom element. Change 21 to 19. Also You need to position (set the position property to anything other than static, you probably want relative in this case) anything you want to give a z-index to.

```
div#header {
    position: relative
    height:70px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index:20;
}
div#navBar {
    position: relative
    height:50px;
    padding-right:240px;
    line-height:45px;
    background:yellow;
    z-index:19;
}
div#header #logo {
    position:relative;
    right:-20px;
    bottom:-20px;
}
```